# Using PHP string in SQL query works when typed in but not when generated via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
        $query = " 

             select * from tablename where userid = :uid AND date = :date

        ";

        $query_params = array( 

                ':uid' => $_SESSION['user']['uid'],
                ':date' => $date   

        ); 

        try 
        { 
             $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
             $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        }
```

I am trying to run this simple SQL query via PHP. When I hard-code a string of a date like `$date = '2016-07-29';` then I get the proper number of results. When I dynamically generate the same string using javascript like

```
$date = '<script> var currentdate = new Date();
                  document.write(currentdate.getFullYear()+"-"+
                  ("0"+(currentdate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+
                  ("0"+currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2));
         </script>';
```

then I get 0 results. Any ideas? Echoing `$date` in both instances produces the same result (type = string).

Comment: Remember that PHP runs *before* output is generated. It's a serverside language. The output simply doesn't exist yet untill PHP is finished. Eg: That javascript string is exactly what it is. A string with Javascript code. The browser doesn't execute it untill PHP has send it as output.

Comment: @icecub So when I use `echo` that javascript really doesn't evaluate until after this query is executed?

Comment: Exactly. It will first run through all your PHP code before actually echoing out that javascript code to your website. However, you can very easily achieve the same in php with `$date = date("Y-m-d");` :)

Comment: @icecub Thanks so much. I really appreciate it. The reason I was trying to use javascript instead of `date()` is because I need the date of the client, not the server. It seems like I'll have to delve into AJAX.

Comment: I think that's the best solution. You could go with PHP: GeoIP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php to make an educated guess on your visitors local date / time, however it requires quite a large database to setup and can't be trusted 100%

Comment: A simple workaround without Ajax would be like creating an empty index html file with your Javascript code getting the users local date and sending it with a POST request to your PHP file on a fast timer. It's not very professional but it gets the job done if you need it quickly :)

Comment: @icecub Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck :)